# Mysql Data in Replicaiton from Azure Database for MYSQL to VM MYSQL

Tags: mysql, azure, virtual-machine, replication

I created Azure Database for MYSQL and also created a VM and installed MYSQL.

I have created the users with privilages in both the servers using the below command.

```
CREATE USER 'syncuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO ' syncuser'@'%';
```

when i tried executing the below command from Azure Database MYSQL it got executed.

```
CALL mysql.az_replication_change_master('11.11.11.11', 'syncuser', 'P@ssword!', 3306, 'mysql-bin.000002', 120, '');
```

however when i tried to execute the below command from VM MYSQL i am getting error has mentioned below highlighted, please help

change master to

```
master_host = 'somedb.mysql.database.azure.com' , 
master_user='myuser', 
master_password='passwrd', 
master_log_file='mysqldb2-bin.000003';
```

**error connecting to master '@mepocdb.mysql.database.azure.com:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references.**

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, just as the error shows that the connection string may not be right. I'm not sure, but you said you created the users with privileges in both the servers. So I think the user and the password od the change master string should be the same:

```
master_host = 'somedb.mysql.database.azure.com' , 
master_user='syncuser', 
master_password='P@ssword!', 
master_log_file='mysqldb2-bin.000003';
```

And I think you should also add the public IP address of the VM to the firewall of the Azure Database for MySQL. And more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-data-in-replication). Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi,As you have informed i have ensured the users and password are same and firewalls are allowed to connect. but still the same.

Comment: @dakshinamurthy Can you connect the Azure database for MYSQL with that user and password in the VM that the on-premise MYSQL in?